# Python3: Grabbing data from Websocket and putting it into a DataFrame

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, websocket

Wondering if anyone can help. I'm trying to grab data from a websocket and put it into a DataFrame without it having multiple dictionaries in each line. The code I'm using to pull from binance is:

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
from binance.enums import *
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

client = Client('api-key', 'api-secret')
tickers = client.get_all_tickers()


df = pd.DataFrame([])
count = 0
bm = None

### Multiplex socket

# Save incoming data
def process_message(msg):
    global count, df, bm
    print("stream: {} data: {}".format(msg['stream'], msg['data']))
    # append message to array

    df = df.append(msg, ignore_index=True)

    count += 1

    with open('klinesmultiplex_socket.csv', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False)
    #df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    #df.to_csv('test.csv')


def initiate():
    global bm
    # Connect to client
    client = Client('api-key', 'api-secret')

    # Setup Socket
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

    # then start the socket manager
    conn_key = bm.start_multiplex_socket(['bnbbtc@kline_1m', 'neobtc@kline_1m'], process_message)

    # start the socket
    bm.start()


initiate()
```

This is what saves in the csv:

```
0,"{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1521847596412, 's': 'NEOBTC', 'k': {'t': 1521847560000, 'T': 1521847619999, 's': 'NEOBTC', 'i': '1m', 'f': 11202559, 'L': 11202604, 'o': '0.00765700', 'c': '0.00765900', 'h': '0.00766000', 'l': '0.00765400', 'v': '182.38000000', 'n': 46, 'x': False, 'q': '1.39674356', 'V': '131.09000000', 'Q': '1.00404646', 'B': '0'}}",neobtc@kline_1m
0,"{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1521847596412, 's': 'NEOBTC', 'k': {'t': 1521847560000, 'T': 1521847619999, 's': 'NEOBTC', 'i': '1m', 'f': 11202559, 'L': 11202604, 'o': '0.00765700', 'c': '0.00765900', 'h': '0.00766000', 'l': '0.00765400', 'v': '182.38000000', 'n': 46, 'x': False, 'q': '1.39674356', 'V': '131.09000000', 'Q': '1.00404646', 'B': '0'}}",neobtc@kline_1m
1,"{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1521847597055, 's': 'BNBBTC', 'k': {'t': 1521847560000, 'T': 1521847619999, 's': 'BNBBTC', 'i': '1m', 'f': 12744199, 'L': 12744341, 'o': '0.00132050', 'c': '0.00131530', 'h': '0.00132200', 'l': '0.00131500', 'v': '5571.10000000', 'n': 143, 'x': False, 'q': '7.33546205', 'V': '2637.29000000', 'Q': '3.47577851', 'B': '0'}}",bnbbtc@kline_1m
0,"{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1521847596412, 's': 'NEOBTC', 'k': {'t': 1521847560000, 'T': 1521847619999, 's': 'NEOBTC', 'i': '1m', 'f': 11202559, 'L': 11202604, 'o': '0.00765700', 'c': '0.00765900', 'h': '0.00766000', 'l': '0.00765400', 'v': '182.38000000', 'n': 46, 'x': False, 'q': '1.39674356', 'V': '131.09000000', 'Q': '1.00404646', 'B': '0'}}",neobtc@kline_1m
```

However, I'm looking for it to look like this (or even to get rid of the value in column 0...not sure what that is):

```
   0, 'kline', 1521847596412, NEOBTC', 1521847560000, 1521847619999, 'NEOBTC', '1m', 11202559, 11202604, 0.00765700, 0.00765900, 0.00766000, 0.00765400, 182.38000000, 46, False, 1.39674356', 131.09000000, 1.00404646,0,neobtc@kline_1m
    0,'kline', 1521847596412, 'NEOBTC', 1521847560000, 1521847619999, 'NEOBTC', '1m', 11202559, 11202604, 0.00765700, 0.00765900, 0.00766000, 0.00765400, 182.38000000, 46, False, 1.39674356, 131.09000000, 1.00404646, 0,neobtc@kline_1m
    1,'kline', 1521847597055, 'BNBBTC', 1521847560000, 1521847619999, 'BNBBTC', '1m', 12744199, 12744341, 0.00132050, 0.00131530, 0.00132200, 0.00131500, 5571.10000000, 143, False, 7.33546205, 2637.29000000, 3.47577851, 0,bnbbtc@kline_1m
    0,'kline', 1521847596412, 'NEOBTC', 1521847560000, 1521847619999, 'NEOBTC', '1m', 11202559, 11202604,0.00765700, 0.00765900, 0.00766000, 0.00765400, 182.38000000, 46, False, 1.39674356, 131.09000000, 1.00404646, 0,neobtc@kline_1m
```

I've tried a bunch of things but can't get it to work: Json to DataFrame, multiple dictionaries to DataFrame, and a few other things. Please let me know if I'm even looking in the right place. Some of the number are shown up with 'xxxx.xxxx' instead of just xxxx.xxxx as well.

What I would eventually like to do is grab all the ticker data and save each ticker to an individual file from the stream above. ie NEOBTC amnd BNBBTC would be saved in their own csv. I only want it to save when 'x': True, however.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on any of my struggles and thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Is the end goal to produce a CSV file, or to just keep the data in a DataFrame in memory and stop writing the file?

Comment: The end goal is to produce a csv file. However, I can produce the csv but the data is as above, ie dictionary within a dictionary but I'd like it to look like the bottom example

Answer (score 4):

In your current code, each time you receive one message, you append it to a DataFrame (n.b. appending to a DataFrame is always slow and never a good idea).  You then append the DataFrame to the file.  So when you receive messages A, B, and C, you write A, A, B, A, B, C.  That's a major bug.

The other problem with your code is that there is no reason to use Pandas for this.  You should use the built-in `csv` module.  Something like this:

```
import csv
columns = ['e', 'E', 's', 'k'] # add whatever JSON keys you want
out = csv. DictWriter(open('klines.csv', 'wb'), columns)
```

Then for each message:

```
out.writerow(msg)
```

This will give you the output format you desire (assuming you add all the columns you need).

If all you need to do with each message is write it to the CSV, you can directly pass the `writerow()` function as the API callback:

```
bm.start_multiplex_socket(['bnbbtc@kline_1m'], out.writerow)
```

This way you don't need `process_message()` at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've entered your code and I think it works but I get an error:    dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'data', 'stream'. I think this is because I have the header=False in the original code. This gets rid of this in the data: ,data,stream
0,"{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1521848434118, 's': 'BNBBTC', 'k': {'t': 1521848400000, 'T': 1521848459999, 's': 'BNBBTC', 'i': '1m', 'f': 12747441, 'L': 12747497, 'o': '0.00130880', 'c': '0.00130890', 'h': '0.00131000', 'l': '0.00130860', 'v': '989.09000000', 'n': 57, 'x': False, 'q': '1.29497482', 'V': '757.98000000'.....

Answer (score 0):

```
from pprint import pprint

retorno = 0
retornoold = 0

def process_m_message(msg):
    global retorno    
    retorno = msg

conn_key = bm.start_multiplex_socket(connstr, process_m_message)
bm.start()

while True:
    if retorno != 0 and retorno != retornoold:        
        pprint(retorno)
        for x in range(0,len(retorno)):
            ...
    retornoold = retorno
```

This is not a clean solution, need some work, but it's a way to get rid of process_m_message